# How can my Ethernet - not used for Internet - and a USB wireless Internet connection work at the same time

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, usb, router

In my Windows 7 box I have an internal Ethernet board
and a USB wireless connection.
I use the wireless for Internet access,
and it works great as long as the Ethernet board is disabled,
but it fails when the Ethernet is enabled.
I need the Ethernet connection to communicate with a local device (an embroidery machine).

I am guessing there is some setting I am missing.
I was using the Ethernet for Internet access at one time (on Windows 7).

I have an unattached building next to my house, I was paying for 2 cable modems, by putting a range extender of the modem in the house, and buying the wireless adapter for my shop desktop I am able to just pay for 1 service. But now I can't run the embroidery machine and be online. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the output of `ipconfig` if you've got both adapters enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Change one of the networks !!!  I suspect that both adaptors are in the same range, and when the WLAN connection is online the router can't find the default gateway because its looking through the wrong interface.

You may be able to fix this by changing one of the networks to a different one of

172.16.x.x
192.168.x.x
10.x.x.x

I note that you could use a smaller network (eg if you are using 192.168.x.x change the subnet mask to 255.255.255.0 (rather then 255.255.0.0) and then make sure that the WIFI is in a different range, for example 192.168.1.x as opposed to 192.168.1.x)